# Power BI Custom Visual development - How to access function from external js

Tags: typescript, powerbi

i am creating custom visual for Power BI, and I would like to use function, that is in external js file.
I added external file to *pbiviz.json* file as below:

```
  "externalJS": [
     "leaflet.js",
     "Polyline.encoded.js",
     "routing.js"
  ],
```

next in *visual.ts* file I have this code: [image]

And this is original [Polyline.encoded.js](https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet.encoded/blob/master/Polyline.encoded.js) file.

Any suggestions how to fix it???

Answer (score 0):

sorry for late answer.

pbiviz.json provides information only for power-bi tools to assembly visual package.

I think you must provide typings of this library in tsconfig.json

About Custom Visuals development you can ask in community form of Power BI in the special section about CV development(community.powerbi.com). There are people who can help you